# Separate string array into multiple arrays

Tags: java, regex

I have String[] array that contains a string with three data points separated by the character ":" like the following string:

***SNSD_OOT:511:127***

I need to extract this values from the String[] array. I tried using statusOxymetry[i] = Arrays.toString(valuesOxymetry[i].split(":")); However I end up with the following data. I need to store each element into an array.

***[SNSD_OOT, 511, 127]***

My goal is to end with 3 arrays, one where anything before the first ":" appears, another one for the data after the first ":", and the final one for the data after the second ":"

```
1stArray[0] = SNSD
2ndArray[0] = 511
3rdArray[0] = 127
```

I need to separate the first, second, and third element into a separate array each. I am feeling a bit confused on how to do this properly.

```
                    String[] valuesOxymetry = message.getData().getString("raw"));
                    int total = valuesOxymetry.length - 2;

                    String[] statusOxymetry = new String[total];
                    String[] hrmOxymetry = new String[total];
                    String[] spo2Oxymetry = new String[total];

                    //ignore first two data points (timestamp)
                    for(int i = 2; i < total; i++) {
                        System.out.println("Pulse values: " + valuesOxymetry[i]);
                        statusOxymetry[i] = Arrays.toString(valuesOxymetry[i].split(":"));
                        System.out.println("Only status " + statusOxymetry[i]);

                    }
```

Comment: Why do you need `3` separate arrays if there are only `3` elements?

Comment: @JacobG. valuesOxymetry is an array of size "n." Each string has 3 elements. I need to create 3 arrays, one for each element in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
for(int i = 2, j = 0; i < total; i++, j++) {
    System.out.println("Pulse values: " + valuesOxymetry[i]);

    String[] values = valuesOxymetry[i].split(":");
    statusOxymetry[j] = values[0];
    hrmOxymetry   [j] = values[1];
    spo2Oxymetry  [j] = values[2];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `String.split` method returns an array. Store that array in a new variable, and use that new variable:

```
String[] splitValues = valuesOxymetry[i].split(":")

statusOxymetry[i] = splitValues[0]; // SNSD_OOT
hrmOxymetry[i] = splitValues[1];    // 511
spo2Oxymetry[i] = splitValues[2];   // 127
```

That said, there may be a cleaner way to do this. For example you could create a class that represents data records as independent entities, instead of striping the data across "parallel arrays."

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
public static void main(String[] ar) throws Exception{

    String dataraw = "SNSD_OOT:511:127";

    //take every array from result list
    //print first element
    toListStringArray(dataraw)
        .forEach(
            e -> System.out.println(e[0])
        );

}

public static List<String[]> toListStringArray(String dataraw){

    //split string
    String[] dataArray = dataraw.split(":");

    //list which contains all arrays
    List<String[]> result = new ArrayList<>();

    //take every element from split
    //put into an array which will contains only that element
    //put array in list
    for(String e : dataArray){
        result.add(new String[]{e});
    }

    return result;

}
```

I don't see why to do this. I also recommend to look at @Joni answer